# AuthenticationManager не связывается

Tags: java

Есть вот такой вот сервис.   Эти 2 штуки не "автоварятся"

`@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;`

`@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;`

Читал, что можно чрз super.authenticationManager() можно переопределить бин, но у меня не выходит. (Видимо из-за того, что я наследуюсь от интерфейса)
Как их "подвязать"?

Весь класс:

```
@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public String findLoggedInUsername() {
    Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
    if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails) {
        return ((UserDetails) userDetails).getUsername();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void autoLogin(String username, String password) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

    authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

    if (authenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

        logger.debug(String.format("Successfully %s auto logged in", username));
    }
}
}
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: Если Спринг не может связать, он пишет почему. Что у тебя в логах? Возможно, ты через бездумные попытки сделать хоть что-то (`super.authenticationManager()`) определил более одного менеджера. Или вообще ни одного. Вот это надо выяснить в логах.

Comment: не находит эти два бина

Comment: `AuthenticationManager`  это бин, который обрабатывает запрос на аутентификацию и решает, можно дать доступ или нет и с какими правами. Спринг предоставляет `ProviderManager`, который реализует этот интерфейс, опрашивая доступные `AuthenticationProvider` один за другим, см https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/overall-architecture.html#core-services-authentication-manager

Твоя задача предоставить какую-то реализацию `AuthenticationProvider`

Answer (score 0):

У тебя вывернуто наизнанку. `UserDetailsService`  должен использоваться менеджером, чтобы разрешить юзеру доступ или запретить, а не наоборот.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public initialize(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    // вот тут можно настроить своего провайдера, напрример
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Эти 2 штуки не "автоварятся"

Что вы имеете ввиду? (конкретно)

Пробовали?

```
@Configuration
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не поможет.

Comment: Это не работает